# What's a good structure for storing user folders?

Tags: unix, directory-structure

We have a Unix server and we need to store content in a folder for each user. We over 40k users currently and hope to have hundreds of thousands or even millions of users.

Having a structure like:

```
myapp.com/user/1001
myapp.com/user/1002
myapp.com/user/1003
```

In the above example, 100* is the user ID. This is obviously not good to have a million folders all at the same level. Even doing an "ls -l" with a couple thousand could be slow. So how about breaking it down like this:

```
myapp.com/user/1/0/0/1
myapp.com/user/1/0/0/2
myapp.com/user/1/0/0/3
```

Would this be a good, scalable structure? Is there an official best-practice?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Yeah, the approach you’ve suggested is quite common, I know it from cache servers.

Comment: I work with a very large data set, and it's updated daily. The current amount of data exceeds terabytes, stored both in disks and eventually written to tapes. The organization used to maintain the data on disks is similar to the one you pointed -- we actually deal dates, but the mapping is just equivalent.

Comment: Great - thanks guys, very helpful. I guys I was just looking for validation :)